# Service class and logging design Scala with Futures

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scalaz

I have a service class that gets some data from a database (for context, I'm using Play! Framework). Here's an example method:

```
  def getAccessToken(id: BSONObjectID): Future[Option[String]] = {
    userDAO.find(id).map {
      case Some(user) =>
        user.settings flatMap (_.accessToken)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to improve the error handling (new to Scala) on this thing as there are a couple things that can go wrong:

1. User might not be found
2. User might be found but `accessToken` might not be set (`accessToken` is an `Option[String]`)

As it stands right now, I can't differentiate between the two. My natural inclination to fix this is to use `\/` from Scalaz and have the return type be `Future[ErrorType \/ String]` and this seems like a reasonable approach. In my controller method, I can for comprehension a bunch of different service methods like this by lifting into a wrapper monad.

But I have the following questions:

1. Should my `ErrorType` extend `Exception`, or should I just use the sealed trait style and just extend from that. I've heard that it is not good practice to use exceptions in Scala, so I'm not sure what the right approach is.
2. How can I handle logging without polluting the controller class with excessive log statements? If a controller class calls a bunch of these service methods, the controller will have to handle several different `ErrorType`s in the for comprehension. Assuming I'm lifting all the monads to a wrapper monad with `?|`, I want to avoid this:

   ```
   accessToken <- service.getAccessToken(id) ?| { error => error match { case Error1 =>
                  logger.error(
                    "Unable to find access token for user: " + id
                      .toString())
                  InternalServerError(
                    ApiResponse("internal_server_error",
                                "Unable to get token."))
                  case Error2 => ...
                }
   ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Future[ErrorType / String] is a bit overkill as Future[T] already can hold either an object of type T or an Exception derived one (see Future.successful(...)/ Future.failed(...))

> Should my ErrorType extend Exception, or should I just use the sealed trait style and just extend from that. I've heard that it is not good practice to use exceptions in Scala, so I'm not sure what the right approach is.

I would recommend to use a class (or a set of classes, one per particular error type), say YourAppException derived from Exception, as you need to handle low level exceptions one way or another anyway.

I agree that *throwing/catching* exceptions is not going very well with functional code and it is better to use Try[T] or Future[T] to return errors in a more explicit way instead. On the other hand there is nothing wrong with using an Exception derived class to hold some error info. It is often useful to wrap the original non-application (say IO) exception in an application one and keep a reference to the initial one in Exception's 'cause' for troubleshooting. It gives an opportunity to provide a more context specific error message.

> How can I handle logging without polluting the controller class with excessive log statements?

Consider encapsulating error messages in Exception derived case classes, representing application errors so you can access the error messsages uniformly using exception.getMessage. It is easy to add some method to YourAppException to construct ApiResponse as well.

```
def getAccessToken(id: BSONObjectID): Future[String] = {
    userDAO.find(id).flatMap {
      case Some(user) =>
        val optToken = user.settings.flatMap (_.accessToken)
        optToken.map(Future.successful).getOrElse(Future.failed(AccessTokenIsInvalid(user)))
      case _ => Future.failed(UserNotFoundError(user))
    }
  }

case class AccessTokenIsInvalid(user: String) 
  extends YourAppException(s"Access token is invalid for user $user") {
}

accessToken <- service.getAccessToken(id) ?| { error => 
           logger.error(error.getMessage)
           InternalServerError(
             ApiResponse("internal_server_error", error.getMessage))
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, you are on a right way. The problem with exceptions is that when something fails it's hard to pattern-match on it to detect a reason.
I would do it like that:

```
sealed trait MyError
object UserNotFound extends MyError
object AuthFailed extends MyError

type MyResult = Either[MyError, String]
```

2) If a program is well-typed logging is necessary in places where information is lost. 
If you deal with, for example, `val x = Future[Either[Error, String]]`, then you haven't throttled potential error yet so logging is optional.
But when you somehow try to extract `Either[MyError, String]` from it you lose information so you should log it.
The same happens when you extract `String` from `Either[MyError, String]`.